# Failed to read BLEND file..... TYPE error in SDNA file

Tags: error

Hi to all Masters out there. I encountered a problem regarding with a certain file that was created and modified weeks ago. when I tried to open it back again to do some revisions but it can't be opened anymore and an error message was displayed saying "X\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX.blend": TYPE error in SDNA file.
any ideas what happended to this?
thanks!

Comment: Your file is somehow corrupted, try appending your data into a new file, one by one until you find the offending datablocks

Comment: Yes, I think it is already a corrupted blend file. I also tried appending it but it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is your case, but if the .blend file was opened in another version of the blender you were editing or even in another engine (eg upbge and armony3d), it may no longer work in the blender.

Comment: thanks! but the blend file was modified with the same version I created it with and was not opened by another program.